# error not changing while running npm install Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...jsesc/-/jsesc-1.0.0.t'
```

> **I applied the following stemps but I still see an error**

C:\Users\nmabasa5\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

```
npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify

npm i npm@latest -g
```